# What percentage of twins has the same gender

Tags: genetics, dna, twins, gender

If 30% of all twins are identical twins, what percentage of twins has the same gender? I thought: all identical twins have the same gender so it’s at least 30%. And of the non-identical twins it’s about 50%. So 50+30=80%?? Correct me if I’m wrong..?

Comment: I agree that same sex twins account for about two-thirds. Note that this means that the naive hypothesis that the three possible configurations BB, BG and GG have equal probability gives the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

You stated:

- 30% of twins are identical
- 50% of non-identical twins have the same gender

Therefore 70% of twins are non-identical and 50% of those will have the same gender. I'll leave the rest of the calculation to you.

Comment: So: 35+30= 65% of twins have the same gender?

Comment: @Mett123 Based on the information you gave, that would be correct.